# Rebase head of master on top of another branch (both already pushed)

Tags: git

I know that there are a lot of similar questions in stackoverflow, but before asking this I did some research and couldn't find a direct answer my question.

My situation is the following: I've a private repo, and am working with another developer. So we are two developers working with a private repository, which means that `push -f` is not the end of the world. This repository will soon go public and, at this point we rater fix mistakes and do a little rework to change history (so that, once the repository goes public, people can work with a solid base of working commits).

Yesterday I've pushed a commit into `master` that, for some reason, only works in my machine and in our dev server, but not in my colleague machine nor the production server.

So we forked a branch (`album`) from a previous commit. My colleague commited several times on this branch. He them pushed the branch to the remote repository (we needed to do this in order to publish his working version to the production server) and we ended up with something like this:

```
master: (previous commits) - C1 - C2 (my "troubled" commit)
                              \
album:                        C3 - C4 - C5 - C6
```

Under normal circumstances I would checkout `master` (in which my troubled commit `C2` is the head) and merge `album` into it.

But this would leave `C2` on the history, plus, since we can't figure out for the life of ours, why my commit broke the environment we feel like it is better to "reaply" the commit the other way around.

What am I thinking of doing:

- checkout `album`
- rebase master on top of it
- delete `album` locally and remotely
- `push -f` master

**Desired result:**

```
master: (previous commits) - C1 - C3 - C4 - C5 - C6 - C2'
```

Where `C2'` should be fixed and working in all machines.

So, am I thinking straight? If not, how would the git gurus out there deal with this?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll do it, I'd get that result this way:

```
$ git checkout album
$ git cherry-pick master
$ git checkout -B master
```

and the ref cleanup's identical.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last bit `git checkout -B master`? When I run it (assuming my current branch is `album`) will it replace my local `master` branch with the contents of the current branch? And, if so, will I be able to push it to my remote repository?

Comment: It's hard to elaborate because there's nothing to it.  That checkout is `cp .git/refs/heads/{album,master}`.  There's nothing more there.  The consequences get interesting right away: you can push anything you've got a ref for, and you make a ref by writing a sha somewhere under .git/refs.  Anything you can do with that, git can do.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear. After `git checkout -B master` I will have two separate branches with the same commits right? So, I will be able to delete `album` with  `git branch -d album` and `git push origin :album`. After that will `master` contain every commit as expected `(previous commits in master) - C1 - C3 - C4 - C5 - C6 - C2`?

Comment: `C2'`, but yes.  `C2` is still there. Branches consist in the parent relations between commits, which are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I believe what you want here is:

- git checkout master
- git reset --hard <sha1 of C1>

At this point C2 is momentarily orphaned and won't be reachable via your branch names. Now you can merge your branch `album` in as you would normally.

Now, to fix the problem of the orphaned C2 commit, you'll want:

- git checkout master
- git cherry-pick <sha1 of C2>

This will leave your master branch looking like:

`master: (previous commits) - C1 - C3 - C4 - C5 - C6 - C2`

Comment: Sounds like a plan (and yes, that is exactly what I want). But won't cherry-picking `C2` on top of `C6` be harder than rebasing it on top of C6 (my original flow, assuming that this can be done)?

Comment: A rebase, in its typical usage, is nothing more than a series of sequential cherry-picks. Whether you use the rebase command or cherry-pick, if you want C2 to follow C6, you'll end up dealing with the same conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase on top of master, yes. That should work fine for where the branch is. Personally, I would clone the repo in a new directory, do a dry run of the rebase, and confirm your results. If all is as desired, repeat the steps in your normal working directory.

Cheers

Comment: I kinda want to do the opposite (rebase a commit of master on top of the branch and then merge / ff the branch on top of master). See the desired result.